# How to use an Android custom library?

Tags: android, sdk, jar

I am trying to create SDK for Android projects that will be a jar file.

The issue I'm having is that the library has a function that returns the MAC address of the device. In order to do so I must use:

```
WifiManager wm = (WifiManager)getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
```

This command requires that my sdk class will inherit from the Activity class and will implement the `onCreate` function.

When I'm trying to consume the library (jar) from another Android project that has a reference to the library I get an errors saying:

```
system service not available to activities before oncreate
```

Even tough my command is inside the onCreate function.

Does anyone have an idea how to solve it? Or do I need to implement the SDK in a different way that will enable me to consume some Android services/features?

I have added an example code for both the library and the project:

The library (compiled into a jar file):

```
public class DeviceDetails
{
    public String MACAddress="";
    public String IMEI="";

    public DeviceDetails(Context context)
    {

        WifiManager wm = (WifiManager)context.getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
        MACAddress=wm.getConnectionInfo().getMacAddress(); 
        TelephonyManager telephonyManager =            (TelephonyManager)context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
        IMEI=telephonyManager.getDeviceId();
    }

}
```

The project that consumes that library

```
public class TestSDKActivity extends Activity
 {
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);


    DeviceDetails d=new DeviceDetails(getApplicationContext());
    String i=d.IMEI;
    String m=d.MACAddress;

      }
}
```

*   The issue has been solved ****

The reason i couldn't get the mac address or the imei was that in order to use wifi service or the telephone service i had to pass the context object from the class that consumed the jar file.

I edited the code.

Comment: Your question doesn't make much sense. Try explaining it better.

Comment: let me try to rephrase, i have a library that i'm creating, lets called it 'lib'. I have an Android project lets called it 'P'. P is using 'lib' and i am trying to get the MAC address which is a member of 'lib'. I am failing to do so and I get null as the response.

Answer (score 0):

If you're calling this within the `onCreate` function, then it hasn't finished loading yet. Thus you can't call system services.

Comment: It makes sense :) , I'll try to move it into the onResume instead of onCreate and see if it works.

Comment: I tried to move the wifi statement to the onResume.Now I'm not getting the error. However the value I get for the MAC is null.

Comment: You're getting the value from `String mac = wm.getConnectionInfo().getMacAddress();` right?

Comment: yes, just finished editing my question with some example codes.

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget to add WIFI permissions into your manifest. that may be the cause of your null as well.

Comment: I have added wifi permission to the project but i didn't compile the the android manifest of the library into the jar as it created some conflicts with my project's manifest (they both has the same name).